# Whats the difference between r += x and r = r + x

Tags: java

Why is that the following code will compile and execute but will yield a wrong result due to integer overflow?

```
int r = 0;
long x = 1_000_000_000_000l;

r += x;
```

While this one will generate a compiler error `incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int`.

```
int r = 0;
long x = 1_000_000_000_000l;

r = r + x;
```

Comment: Because the Java Language Specification says so?

Comment: Read [JLS 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), specifically "_`E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`_". Note the Casts.